# What was the First Windows Written in?

Tags: windows, operating-system

when Bill Gates and Paul Allen made The first Windows how did they do it?
 what exactly was it coded in?
 i was just wondering because i was thinking about early computer coding and such then i thought how did they make the Windows we use today.
 Because now all the coding us programmers do we use operating systems to do so so how was the base operating system made?! and what ever windows was written in is that the same for mac and linux?

just thought it was an interesting question !

Comment: Those guys had another os before windows.

Comment: yeah thats what i thought

Comment: They somehow managed to turn DOS into something that made them strong enough to talk back to IBM.

Comment: Q-DOS (later Microsoft DOS 1.0) was written in assembler:  http://www.skrause.org/computers/dos_history.shtml.  Later versions of DOS ... and early versions of Windows ... used C and assembler.  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/history

Comment: Its all actually very interesting stuff > its cool to go a look at pictures of Windows 1.0, 2.0 ,3.0 and 3.1 then a big change to Windows 95 its awesome to see the progression!

Comment: @Serial, yeah it is super fun to watch the progression. Even check out the progression of the Mac operating system as well, especially during Steve Job's time at NextStep. Very cool stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well If you are curious about the first operating system released by Microsoft. This link will help you.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_1.01

Comment: Actually really interesting stuff